# Can I set Mail to only send from one email address whatever the account?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I use 2 different email addresses, and I have recently forwarded one to the other.

Eventually, I'm going to root out the first address and only use the second. But right now, **in the second email box**, when I'm replying to an email that was **sent to the first email address** (the address i'm going to root out), Mail defaults to **sending mail from that email address rather than from the second email address**.

Is this normal behavior, or is there a way to always reply from the second email address?

Comment: hmm. maybe something in the rules tab under preferences? perhaps if you can set you forwarded mail under one "If" then you can redirect it to your email and send from there. wild guess though

Answer (score 5):

In the `Mail.app` preferences you can select the outgoing Mail server.
Changing it to your preferred account should be enough.

[image]

However, in case this is not enough you could delete the unwanted outgoing servers by editing the SMTP server list:

[image: bla]

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm...not seem o be working that way. iCloud appears to insist that you use t's own SMTP. Anything else it gives you the cryptic error "you can't leave the incoming mail server black" which is actually greyed out and un=modifiable. So...no solution there.

Comment: @Fish iCloud appears to be a special case then. Unlike for other accounts - Apple has greyed out the entries for email address, full name and incoming mail server when using iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

On the odd chance that I'm reading this differently than you intend. You might want to look at the answer in [Duplicate mail settings...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35700/duplicated-mail-settings-caused-email-loss-in-mail-on-lion/36796#36796).

This will work for you if you just want to change the From address. If you really intend to change the server that sends the mail then gentmatt has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Apple -Mail 4.6, go to Mail Preferences, click on "composing", select the outgoing account from the "Send new messages from" box.